# How can I override the Actions buttons of Material-Table of react

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/) in the project we are working on. I need to override the Add button (+ button) and edit button of material-table (marked in the sample image attached), instead of inline adding/editing feature of material-table I want to have a Dialog box (my customized component) should popup in which users will enter their data, then on clicking save button an API call will be performed.

Is there a way to do it? Can I use EditRow props of Materialtable? If yes can someone give a small example of it on how to use EditRow?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this with the following solution given by a Material-Table contributor Matt Oestreich. I had to use Actions property with my custom onClick handler for custom edit and similarly for Adding set isFreeAction to true in actions prop.

[sample code box demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tablecustomedit-add-2di09)
For custom edit operation pass the actions properties like below:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'edit',
      tooltip: 'Edit Row',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Code to display custom Dialog here
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

For custom add operation pass the actions properties along with isFreeAction prop:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'add',
      tooltip: 'Add Row',
      // This makes add button to appear in table toolbar instead for each row
      isFreeAction: true 
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Code to display custom Dialog here
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

my final code would look something like this:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'edit',
      tooltip: 'Edit Row',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Code to display custom Dialog here
      }
    },
    {
      icon: 'add',
      tooltip: 'Add Row',
      // This makes add button to appear in table toolbar instead for each row
      isFreeAction: true 
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Code to display custom Dialog here
      }
    },
  ]}
/>
```