# How do i override the tooltip of the default action button in Material Table?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) for their table. In their editable example, there is the Add action button but i would like to override and rename the tooltip from "add" to "add something else".

[image]

I have looked at another similar stack overflow question -> [How can I override the Actions buttons of Material-Table of react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231091/how-can-i-override-the-actions-buttons-of-material-table-of-react). However, the solution that they proposed replaced the default add button completely. What I wanted is to retain the functionality of the default add row button and just change the naming of the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the localization like this:

```
 localization={{
        body: {
          addTooltip: 'Add something else',
       }
}}
```